# estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method

Tags: python, scikit-learn

when I try to run the code in python I encounter this problem  , how can I solve it?

```
 ---> 95     validation(sm_classifier, x_test_normal_s, y_n2_test, y_test, classes_names, ' NSLKDD SAE-SAE(test)')
         96     #if __name__ == "__main__":main() ## with if
         97 
    
    <ipython-input-23-95022ce9a680> in validation(classifier, data, y_data, y_target, class_names, title)
         52         print ("No accuracy to be computed")
         53     else:
    ---> 54         accuracy = model_selection.cross_val_score(classifier,x, y_target, scoring='accuracy')
         55         print("Accuracy: "+ str(accuracy))
         56     precision = model_selection.cross_val_score(self.classifier, x, target, scoring='precision')
    
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
        130     cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
        131     cv_iter = list(cv.split(X, y, groups))
    --> 132     scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
        133     # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are
        134     # independent, and that it is pickle-able.
    
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\scorer.py in check_scoring(estimator, scoring, allow_none)
        248     if not hasattr(estimator, 'fit'):
        249         raise TypeError("estimator should be an estimator implementing "
    --> 250                         "'fit' method, %r was passed" % estimator)
        251     if isinstance(scoring, six.string_types):
        252         return get_scorer(scoring)
    
    TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, <__main__.Softmax object at 0x00000000048D1F98> was passed
```

..............................

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random
from operator import itemgetter

class Softmax:
    #from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer; Tracer()() 

    def __init__(self, batch_size=50, epochs=1000, learning_rate=1e-2, reg_strength=1e-5, weight_update='adam'):
        self.W = None
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.reg_strength = reg_strength
        self.weight_update = weight_update

    def train(self, X, y):
        n_features = X.shape[1]
        n_classes = y.max() + 1
        self.W = np.random.randn(n_features, n_classes) / np.sqrt(n_features/2)
        config = {'reg_strength': self.reg_strength, 'batch_size': self.batch_size,
                'learning_rate': self.learning_rate, 'eps': 1e-8, 'decay_rate': 0.99,
                'momentum': 0.9, 'cache': None, 'beta_1': 0.9, 'beta_2':0.999,
                'velocity': np.zeros(self.W.shape)}
        c = globals()['Softmax']
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            loss, config = getattr(c, self.weight_update)(self, X, y, config)
            print ("Epoch:" +str(epoch)+", Loss: "+str(loss))

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.argmax(X.dot(self.W), 1)

    def loss(self, X, y, W, b, reg_strength):
        sample_size = X.shape[0]
        predictions = X.dot(W) + b

        # Fix numerical instability
        predictions -= predictions.max(axis=1).reshape([-1, 1])

        # Run predictions through softmax
        softmax = math.e**predictions
        softmax /= softmax.sum(axis=1).reshape([-1, 1])

        # Cross entropy loss
        loss = -np.log(softmax[np.arange(len(softmax)), y]).sum() 
        loss /= sample_size
        loss += 0.5 * reg_strength * (W**2).sum()

        softmax[np.arange(len(softmax)), y] -= 1
        dW = (X.T.dot(softmax) / sample_size) + (reg_strength * W)
        return loss, dW

    def sgd(self, X, y, config):
        items = itemgetter('learning_rate', 'batch_size', 'reg_strength')(config)
        learning_rate, batch_size, reg_strength = items

        loss, dW = self.sample_and_calculate_gradient(X, y, batch_size, self.W, 0, reg_strength)
 
        self.W -= learning_rate * dW
        return loss, config

    def sgd_with_momentum(self, X, y, config):
        items = itemgetter('learning_rate', 'batch_size', 'reg_strength', 'momentum')(config)
        learning_rate, batch_size, reg_strength, momentum = items

        loss, dW = self.sample_and_calculate_gradient(X, y, batch_size, self.W, 0, reg_strength)

        config['velocity'] = momentum*config['velocity'] - learning_rate*dW
        self.W += config['velocity']
        return loss, config

    def rms_prop(self, X, y, config):
        items = itemgetter('learning_rate', 'batch_size', 'reg_strength', 'decay_rate', 'eps', 'cache')(config)
        learning_rate, batch_size, reg_strength, decay_rate, eps, cache = items

        loss, dW = self.sample_and_calculate_gradient(X, y, batch_size, self.W, 0, reg_strength)

        cache = np.zeros(dW.shape) if cache == None else cache
        cache = decay_rate * cache + (1-decay_rate) * dW**2
        config['cache'] = cache

        self.W -= learning_rate * dW / (np.sqrt(cache) + eps)
        return loss, config

    def adam(self, X, y, config):
        items = itemgetter('learning_rate', 'batch_size', 'reg_strength', 'eps', 'beta_1', 'beta_2')(config)
        learning_rate, batch_size, reg_strength, eps, beta_1, beta_2 = items
        config.setdefault('t', 0)
        config.setdefault('m', np.zeros(self.W.shape))
        config.setdefault('v', np.zeros(self.W.shape))

        loss, dW = self.sample_and_calculate_gradient(X, y, batch_size, self.W, 0, reg_strength)

        config['t'] += 1
        config['m'] = config['m']*beta_1 + (1-beta_1)*dW
        config['v'] = config['v']*beta_2 + (1-beta_2)*dW**2
        m = config['m']/(1-beta_1**config['t'])
        v = config['v']/(1-beta_2**config['t'])
        self.W -= learning_rate*m/(np.sqrt(v)+eps)
        return loss, config

    def sample_and_calculate_gradient(self, X, y, batch_size, w, b, reg_strength):
        random_indices = random.sample(range(X.shape[0]), batch_size)
        X_batch = X[random_indices]
        y_batch = y[random_indices]
        return self.loss(X_batch, y_batch, w, b, reg_strength)
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, your `sm_classifier` is of type `Softmax` which is not a sklearn `Estimator` car it does not have the `fit` method. Can you give the implemenation of your `Softmax` class ?

Comment: when I run this code    "print(sm_classifier)"  the output
<__main__.Softmax object at 0x00000000048D1F98>

Answer (score 0):

It should work (or atleast, it fixes the current error) if you change

```
def train(self, X, y):
```

to

```
def fit(self, X, y):
```

A valid sklearn  estimator needs `fit` and `predict` methods.

---

Check this out
[How to create a custom Sklearn Estimator class](http://danielhnyk.cz/creating-your-own-estimator-scikit-learn/)

Try replacing:

```
class Softmax:
```

By:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
class Softmax(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot clone object '<__main__.Softmax object at 0x000000000861CF98>' (type <class '__main__.Softmax'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
selector = GeneticSelectionCV(estimator=None,//check this
                              scoring=evaluate,
                              cv=5,
                              verbose=1,
                              n_population=50,
                              crossover_proba=0.5,
                              mutation_proba=0.2,
                              n_generations=40,
                              crossover_independent_proba=0.5,
                              mutation_independent_proba=0.05,
                              tournament_size=3,
                              caching=True,
                              n_jobs=-1)
```

I was also troubled by this today, but I later discovered that the reason is that the estimator needs to pass in a variable.